# Share mouse and keyboard on android device

Tags: android, remote, synergy, scrcpy

Synergy and Barrier do something similar.
scrcpy - can control android, but it displays a window and transmits video - which is not necessary.

Roughly speaking, the goal is to add a screen to which the mouse will move and function. This screen is android phone.

Even simpler: I want to put android on the side of the laptop to be able to move the cursor there from ubuntu and click or type.

Comment: The actual question is missing... and the information, which Ubuntu version you are using. Please edit your question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [DeskDock](https://www.fdmobileinventions.com/deskdock-server/) for sharing ubuntu mouse and keyboard on android